# Is there any method to store conditional statement in java?

Tags: java, android, if-statement, conditional-statements

I wanted to know if there is any method to store if else condition in java? What I mean is like having a variable to represent the condition. This is my original code

```
private OnClickListener click2 = new OnClickListener() { 

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            tv1.setText("");
            List<Integer> mClickedButtonIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            int[] mDesiredOrder = new int[] { ans1.getId(), ans2.getId(), ans3.getId(),
                                              ans4.getId(), ans5.getId() }; 

            mClickedButtonIds.add(v.getId());
            if (mClickedButtonIds.size() >= mDesiredOrder.length )

            {            
                if (mClickedButtonIds.get(0) == mDesiredOrder[0] 
                    && mClickedButtonIds.get(1) == mDesiredOrder[1] 
                    && mClickedButtonIds.get(2) == mDesiredOrder[2]
                    && mClickedButtonIds.get(3) == mDesiredOrder[3]
                    && mClickedButtonIds.get(4) == mDesiredOrder[4]
                    )
                {
                    tv1.setText("Correct!");
                }
                else 
                {
                    tv1.setText("Try Again!");
                }
                mClickedButtonIds.clear();
             }
        }
 };
```

I plan to change it to something like this

```
private OnClickListener click2 = new OnClickListener() { 

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            tv1.setText("");
            List<Integer> mClickedButtonIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            int[] mDesiredOrder = new int[] { ans1.getId(), ans2.getId(), ans3.getId(),
                                              ans4.getId(), ans5.getId(), ans6.getId() };   

            switch (main)
            {
            case 4 : Variable x = mClickedButtonIds.get(0) == mDesiredOrder[0] 
                    && mClickedButtonIds.get(1) == mDesiredOrder[1] 
                    && mClickedButtonIds.get(2) == mDesiredOrder[2]
                    && mClickedButtonIds.get(3) == mDesiredOrder[3];

            case 5 : Variable x = mClickedButtonIds.get(0) == mDesiredOrder[0] 
                    && mClickedButtonIds.get(1) == mDesiredOrder[1] 
                    && mClickedButtonIds.get(2) == mDesiredOrder[2]
                    && mClickedButtonIds.get(3) == mDesiredOrder[3]
                    && mClickedButtonIds.get(4) == mDesiredOrder[4];

            case 6: Variable x = mClickedButtonIds.get(0) == mDesiredOrder[0] 
                    && mClickedButtonIds.get(1) == mDesiredOrder[1] 
                    && mClickedButtonIds.get(2) == mDesiredOrder[2]
                    && mClickedButtonIds.get(3) == mDesiredOrder[3]
                    && mClickedButtonIds.get(4) == mDesiredOrder[4]
                    && mClickedButtonIds.get(5) == mDesiredOrder[5];
            }

            mClickedButtonIds.add(v.getId());
            if (mClickedButtonIds.size() >= mDesiredOrder.length )

            {            
                if (x)

                {
                    tv1.setText("Correct!");
                }
                else 
                {
                    tv1.setText("Try Again!");
                }
                mClickedButtonIds.clear();
             }
        }
 };
```

The `Variable x` is something which I would like to ask. Is there any method to do so or is there any `variable` that can store if else condition. Cause the original code, it is fixed to 5 clicks. Now I want the number of required clicks to change according to how many clicks the user want.

Comment: Does x have known inputs and a known subset of conditions?

Comment: What do you mean "*variable that can store if else condition*"? This sentence make me stress.

Comment: or is x just a boolean?

Comment: You can use SharedPreferences to save a variable value to the "disk". So you can reload it on next run.

Comment: I am not sure what `variable` to use that why i put it as `Variable x`. can a `boolean` work on this 1?

Comment: I think you need to use `for` statement and move your comparison code to a method, parametrized by click count

Comment: Would I be correct in saying that you want to be able to swap in (for example) the condition `condition1.length()>condition2;` for `condition1.length()+condition2<5;` or `condition1.length()<condition2;` etc by changing x

Comment: What I mean is like if `main` which is a variable is equal to 5 then the conditional statement for the if statement will change

Comment: @user3153613 So is [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20951705/2187042) broadly what you mean?

Comment: It looks to me like `mClickedButtonIds` needs to be a class field, rather than a local variable in your method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the code snippet, consider a loop:

```
boolean result = true;
for (int i = 0; i < main; ++i) {
    result = result && mClickedButtonIds.get(i) == mDesiredOrder[i];
    if (!result)
        break; // short-circuit out from loop if false
}

// now you can use "result" to test whether the condition matched all "main" ids
if (result) {
    // correct
} else {
    // bzzt, try again
}
```

Comment: +1 This looks like the correct approach. I was just editing my answer along these lines.

Comment: if like that then after that i put the `result` in the if statement like `if (result) {}`?

Comment: you are very smart it worked. It work better than using a switch statement

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, that you want x to be a condition that you may change programatically (but which conforms to some structure) then you can do this using an interface `Question` and classes which implement that interface

```
public interface Question {
    boolean getResponse(String condition1, int condition2);
}

public class StringIsLongCondition implements Question{

    public boolean getResponse(String condition1, int condition2) {
        return condition1.length()>condition2;
    }

}

public class StringIsShortCondition implements Question{

    public boolean getResponse(String condition1, int condition2) {
        return condition1.length()<condition2;
    }

}
```

Then use like

```
Question x;

//some code that selects the question
x= new StringIsShortCondition();

if(x.getResponse(someString, someInt){
     //do something
}
```